# How to remove everything in the first column only after dot?

Tags: awk

I am having multiple files like this:

```
head Stomach.v7.egenes.txt
ENSG00000238009.2 RP11-34P13.7  1  89295 129223  - 2073 1.03557 343.245
ENSG00000237683.5   AL627309.1  1 134901 139379  - 2123 1.02105 359.907
ENSG00000235146.2 RP5-857K21.2  1 523009 530148  + 4098 1.03503 592.973
ENSG00000231709.1 RP5-857K21.1  1 521369 523833  - 4101 1.07053 559.642
ENSG00000223659.1 RP5-857K21.5  1 562757 564390  - 4236 1.05527 595.015
ENSG00000237973.1 hsa-mir-6723  1 566454 567996  + 4247 1.05299 592.876
```

how do I remove everything after the first dot in the first column in every file? to get for this example this:

```
ENSG00000238009 RP11-34P13.7  1  89295 129223  - 2073 1.03557 343.245
ENSG00000237683   AL627309.1  1 134901 139379  - 2123 1.02105 359.907
ENSG00000235146 RP5-857K21.2  1 523009 530148  + 4098 1.03503 592.973
ENSG00000231709 RP5-857K21.1  1 521369 523833  - 4101 1.07053 559.642
ENSG00000223659 RP5-857K21.5  1 562757 564390  - 4236 1.05527 595.015
ENSG00000237973 hsa-mir-6723  1 566454 567996  + 4247 1.05299 592.876
```

I tried doing this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" "} {gsub(/\./, " ", $1)} 1' Stomach.v7.egenes.txt > test.txt
```

but this does not give me the output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I remove everything after the first dot in the first column

It is actually quote simple using `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/\..*$/, "", $1)} 1' file
```

```
ENSG00000238009 RP11-34P13.7 1 89295 129223 - 2073 1.03557 343.245
ENSG00000237683 AL627309.1 1 134901 139379 - 2123 1.02105 359.907
ENSG00000235146 RP5-857K21.2 1 523009 530148 + 4098 1.03503 592.973
ENSG00000231709 RP5-857K21.1 1 521369 523833 - 4101 1.07053 559.642
ENSG00000223659 RP5-857K21.5 1 562757 564390 - 4236 1.05527 595.015
ENSG00000237973 hsa-mir-6723 1 566454 567996 + 4247 1.05299 592.876
```

If you're using gnu awk then you can use in place file editing and avoid the loop:

```
awk -i inplace '{sub(/\..*$/, "", $1)} 1' *.v7.egenes.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, to do this in the loop for all files ending in *.v7.egenes.txt would I do this:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for f in *.v7.egenes.txt
do 
   awk '{sub(/\..*$/, "", $1)} 1' "$f" > "temp_file" && mv "temp_file" "$f"
done

Comment: @anamaria or with GNU awk `awk -i inplace '{sub(/\..*$/, "", $1)} 1' *.v7.egenes.txt`, i.e. use "inplace" editing instead of a loop.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, let me add this gnu awk command in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with sed :

```
$ cat data
ENSG00000238009.2 RP11-34P13.7  1  89295 129223  - 2073 1.03557 343.245
ENSG00000237683.5   AL627309.1  1 134901 139379  - 2123 1.02105 359.907

$ cat data | sed -E 's/(^.?{15})\.[0-9]/\1/'
ENSG00000238009 RP11-34P13.7  1  89295 129223  - 2073 1.03557 343.245
ENSG00000237683   AL627309.1  1 134901 139379  - 2123 1.02105 359.907
```